# Calculate percentiles from 0 to 100 with step 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `score` column in pandas dataframe `df` for which I need to calculate percentiles from `0` to `100` inclusive with a step of `1` `(0.00, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ..., 0.99, 1)`.
In `R`, this is easily done with the following code:

```
perc <- quantile(df$score, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
```

How to implement this in Python?

Comment: Did you try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html or https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quantile` to get it in pandas as well.

For example:

```
df['score'].quantile(0.9)
```

To get all the quantiles from 0 to 1 I believe something like this should work:

```
perc = [df['score'].quantile(p) for p in np.arange(0,1,0.01)]
```